# Creating a stream of single file atoms

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, experimental-technique, accelerator-physics

How do you go about creating a stream of single file atoms?

The aim is to fire a stream of single file atoms (hydrogen, helium) down a vacuum and detect there arrival on the opposite end. Any tips or papers would be a great help.

Comment: Building a particle accelerator at home is possible, but it will take some doing depending on what kinds of parameters you desire in terms of energy and collimation. To get "single file" you just turn down the intensity until the separation is good enough for your needs. Typical beams will be charged (i.e. ions not neutral atoms), and making a neutral beam is considerably harder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ed051p620) for some guidelines (paywalled, unfortunately). Bearing in mind the paper is nearly forty years old I imagine the technology has progressed a bit since the paper was published, but it's still a good guide to what is required. It might be worth a citation search to see if any more recent publications have improved on the design.

In the days when I had to design undergraduate experiments the Journal of Chemical Education was an invaluable resource. There may well be other similar publications more targeted towards Physics. Perhaps others more familiar with the literature could comment.